# SSAS: Show distinct count measure with unknown member

Tags: ssas, mdx, business-intelligence, olap

I have a measure that counts distincted ID's on some fact table.
Let's say it looks like this:

```
[id] [linkedtableid] [datecolumn]
```

> 1 someid date1
>
> 2 someid date1
>
> 3 someid date1
>
> 4 someid date1
>
> 5 null date1

You may see that for date1 there is 5 distinct rows. But in my case it results count = 4. I thought that this can be connected somehow with UnknownMember processing, but I ended up with nothing with this assumption. I've already tried everything in my cube solution, but can't find the reason of such behavior. It seems like row with **null** value in it just doesn't count by distinct count function.

Also, if I fill this **null** value in relational DB and then reprocess the cube, all is counting correctly.

I probably missed something, maybe some option somewhere.

Comment: Tabular or Multidimensional?

Comment: @GregGalloway The problem is in OLAP cube

Comment: COUNT(NULL)  will be null so if you want to count NULL as a distinct value you will have to convert that value to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by removing unneeded relations between the measure for distinct count and dimensions. There was 2 other dimensions, one connected through direct link, one through referenced. I don't know why nulls were not calculated there, maybe because of unability to link via reference link with null-valued field.